# how to copy or backup files ignoring dot files

Tags: backup, dot-files

I want to back-up all files from my laptop partitions to external HDD.

I ran, for example

```
cp -a /med*/ravb*/*00   /med*/ravb*/M*L*/7.3GB_CP && echo "7.3GB BACKED UP PROPERLY" || echo "7.3GB FAILED TO BACK UP"
```

The issue is that dot files are also getting included which I don't want.
What should I do so as to ignore all dot files for backing up.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why not use `rsync` instead?  It's made for the job!

```
rsync -uan --progress --exclude=".*" <source> <destination>
```

The above will list all the files to be archived without actually copying anything.  Check that the list is correct, then run it again with the `n` option removed in order to copy the files (you could also remove the `--progress` for a quieter experience).

To expand, the options above are:-

`u` - 'update' - only copy newer files.

`a` - 'archive'

`n` - 'dry-run` - don't copy, just list what it would do.

`--progress` - show progress of copy

`--exclude=".*"` - exclude files that begin with a dot

Comment: Looks great! Yes this is what I wanted. I will run it & update you.

Comment: Yesterday I backed up all the partitions from laptop to my external HDD using `rsync`. It's a superb backup tool. Yes you are right, it's made for the job!!! Till now I've used tar, cpio & cp for backup. But this command `rsync` is the best. The task that seemed to be a bit complex, `rsync` made it very very easy & comfortable. Really a great versatile command. Had I used tar, then for viewing any backup file, I would have to open with tar archive application (which doesn't give a good interface to view) or I would have to recover from the archive. But with `rsync` no such issue.

Comment: One may possibly want to add `--include='*/'` before the exclusion, to include any directory. Otherwise this would skip hidden directories.